# Using scope to calculate SUM from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two db tables with following fields:

```
log_lines: id, user_id, date
fragments: id, log_line_id, amount
```

Corresponding models:

**models/log_lines.rb**

```
class LogLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fragments, dependent: :destroy

  def total_amount
    fragments.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

**models/fragments.rb**

```
class Fragment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :log_line
end
```

I want to get the amount sum depending user_id. The sql query that does the job:

> SELECT SUM(f.amount) FROM log_lines AS ll LEFT JOIN fragments AS f ON
>   f.log_line_id = ll.id WHERE ll.user_id = 74123;

I've created `total_amount` method in `LogLine` model and calling it from `LogLine`
controller:

```
amount = 0
ll_list = LogLine.where(:user_id => user_id)
ll_list.each { |ll| amount += ll.total_amount }
```

Actually it works, but I think its not efficient way to implement it. Because many database queries are executed during such collection of data.

Would it be possible to implement this via one `scope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible via one `scope`. You could use:

```
class Logline < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :user_amount, ->(user_id) { 
    select('sum(fragments.amount')
    .joins('LEFT JOIN fragments ON fragments.log_line_id = log_line.id')
    .where('log_line.user_id = ?', user_id)
  }
end
```

Another way to do it:

```
class Logline < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :user_amount, ->(user_id) {
    joins('LEFT JOIN fragments ON fragments.log_line_id = log_line.id')
    .where(fragments: { user_id: user_id })
    .sum('fragments.amount')
  }
end
```